# Do script tags and link tags go inside asp:content or outside

Tags: asp.net

I have a page which has a masterpage.  Do I put script and link tags inside the asp:content place holders or outside or does it matter.

When I put it outside, I get the following warning:

Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see five (or 8) ways of doing it:

1. In the codebehind (.cs or .vb) using:

   - Scriptmanager.RegisterClientScriptinclude - using an absolute/relative path
   - Scriptmanager.RegisterClientScriptInclude - using an embedded resource
   - Scriptmanager.RegisterSlientScriptBlock - with your source inside
2. Adding it inline to your ASPX page in the designer
3. Sticking it inside the asp:content where the content lives inside the body tag.
4. Sticking it inside the asp:content where the content lives inside the head (**You've said this isn't an option, so ignore this**).
5. Adding it programmatically using the ScriptManager inside a control you use on the page as above.

*"Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls"* - did you forget the runat="server"?

Answer (score 6):

If it's scripts and links for *all* pages, it should go outside any ContentPlaceHolders. If it's scripts and links for *this* page, it should go inside a Content inside the head. If it's default scripts, put it inside a head ContentPlaceHolder, and it can be replaced by the child page if needed. (VS usually complains about a ContentPlaceHolder in the head, but it works fine for me).

```
// master Page
<head runat="server">
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
      <!-- Default scripts and CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
   <!-- Mandatory scripts and css -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   Master Page!
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="body" runat="server" />
</body>

// Child (no JQuery)
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" />
   <!-- Don't need JQuery -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="body" runat="server">
   Child Page!
</asp:Content>

// Child 2 (with JQuery)
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="body" runat="server">
   Child Page!
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: It seems to work even though it's complaining and I have it outside, but what if I don't have a head placeholder.

Comment: Add one. ;) I usually end up with at least 3 placeholders: 1 head for default scripts and styles, 1 head for adding scripts and styles, and 1 content.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to `<asp:Content />` tags, you can't put anything outside of them in an `.aspx` page.  So you're limited to putting them inside the `<asp:Content />` tag.  If you want `<script />` and `<link />` tags you need to either put a `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder />` in the `<head>` of your master page, or add them dynamically via the Page's `Controls` collection.

Answer (score 1):

Outside. Tthe inside of the ContentPlaceholders is going to be replaced with content from your pages anyhow so it doesn't make much sense to put anything in there.

Answer (score 1):

outside. in the master page

The place holders are the wrapping controls for pages which descend from master pages.

Answer (score 1):

Use asp.net scriptreference tag in master page to add reference to javascript file and you will be able to access all you need in the javascript file as if you would have added to the local page.